# Dynamically add v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a select tag on my form and want to add v-model to it.
However I cannot directly add the attribute to the tag as it's auto-generated on server-side.

How can I dynamically add v-model to these select tags?

html

```
<div id="app">
<select id="place" name="place">
  <option value="Tokyo">Tokyo</option>
  <option value="Osaka">Osaka</option>
</select>
  <select id="date" name="date">
    <option value="5/1">5/1</option>
    <option value="5/2">5/2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

javascript

```
// these will NOT work
document.getElementById("place").setAttribute("v-model","place");
document.getElementById("date").setAttribute("v-model","date");

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    place: 'Tokyo',
    date: '5/1'
  }
})
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the HTML added asynchronously? Because otherwise, your code *will* work. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/LydMwd?editors=1010

Comment: you will most proably simply need to ensure that you add the attribute before initializing vue

Comment: you can't  "augment" existing HTML elements with Vue behaviours this way, or any way really. Vue has to render those elements itself from a template in some form or shape, and the necessary directives, like v-model, have to be present in this template.